# How to call a method once the completion block finish?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, block

I want to call the `signUp` method first, once I got the userID, I need to call the another method `normalSignupMethod`.

```
[ConnectionObj signUp:user];
[helper normalSignupMethod:dict];
```

**signUp Method:**

```
[MYRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
    // Sign up was successful
    // Store user id
    [SingletonClass sharedMySingleton].userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",response.data[@"id"]];   

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    // Handle error here
    NSLog(@" error in creating session %@", response.error);
    [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:NSLocalizedString(@"SignUp to Chat error!", nil)];
}];
```

This I how I have called:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create(); 
       dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    NSLog(@"Block1");
    [ConnectionObj signUp:user];
});

dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {

    NSLog(@"Group notify");
    [helper normalSignupMethod:dict];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    });
});
```

Block 1 executed first, and then group notify called. But I'm getting the userID after the normalSignupMethod is finished. How to wait for a signUp method to get userID before calling the normalSignupMethod?

Comment: Why to introduce accidental complexity and not to use delegates? If you use delegates this problem will not occur.

Comment: Have you tried using `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave` ? So that it waits for the first execution to finish

Comment: You did not include the definition of the `signUp:` method. You specified `signUp:successBlock:errorBlock:` instead, which gives you a hook to call additional things in the blocks for exactly the purpose you want. @suhit and @ndoc show you how to go, basically. Doing any dispatch stuff strikes me as very odd, follow their leads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `block` with your `signUp` method like this and pass the `Bool` completion value to check is it called successfully or not. So change your method declaration like this.

```
-(void)signUp:(QBUser*)user andHandler:(void (^)(BOOL result))completionHandler;
```

And its definition

```
-(void)signUp:(QBUser*)user andHandler:(void (^)(BOOL result))completionHandler {
    [MYRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
        [SingletonClass sharedMySingleton].userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",response.data[@"id"]];   
        completionHandler(YES);
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
       // Handle error here
        NSLog(@" error in creating session %@", response.error);
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:NSLocalizedString(@"SignUp to Chat error!", nil)];
        completionHandler(NO);
    }];
}
```

Now call this method like this.

```
[ConnectionObj signUp:user andHandler:^(BOOL result) {
    if(result) {
        [helper normalSignupMethod:dict];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call the `normalSignupMethod` once the `signUp:successBlock` request returns to `successBlock`

```
[MYRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
        // Sign up was successful
        // Store user id
        [SingletonClass sharedMySingleton].userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",response.data[@"id"]]; 

        //call the signup method 
        [helper normalSignupMethod:dict];

    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        // Handle error here
        NSLog(@" error in creating session %@", response.error);
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:NSLocalizedString(@"SignUp to Chat error!", nil)];
    }];
```